# How to insert a new row in a list in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have so many records in a custom list. How to insert a new row between two records (for example between list items with IDs 31 and 32) using browser. Could you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: How do you mean 'between' two records? How are records sorted?

Comment: I want to insert a new record between already existing records which has ids 31 and 32

Comment: Are you referring to `SPListItem.Id`?

Comment: Yes,But I want to do it using browser.It doesn't matter if ids changes for this list

Comment: Why don't you create a new column that you can change as needed for ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert list item between two list items using a browser. That would mean changing the internal ID's of list items which is AFAIK not supported.

Comment: Thank you so much Slaven. But i found an answer for this in  the following blog https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/edd2338d-b7b4-4c90-9c59-9ee97e9b074e/inserting-a-row-in-the-middle-of-a-sharepoint-list

Comment: Please let me know if that works for you. Somehow I doubt that Excel add-in can change list item internal IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own custom ID column (number format) and sort on that using a custom view. Then if you need a row b/w 1 and 2 you can number it 1.5

Done.